# Problema jQuery.parseJSON dentro de success dentro de la peticion ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net

Hola comunidad estoy trabajando con columnas dinámicas y necesito parsear mi cadena data para trabajar con dichas columnas dinámicas pero al ejecutarlo muestra error en la consola. Espero me puedan ayudar aquí coloco código. La cadena devuelta de mi servidor es esta.

```
"[\r\n  {\r\n    \"id_Persona\": 1,\r\n    \"Sucursal\": \"Mexico\",\r\n    \"Nombre\": \"Pedro\",\r\n
```

Este es mi WebMethod de mi webForms. La cadena de arriba es devuelta por mi webMethod

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string Persona(int id_Persona, string Sucursal, int id_Rol) 
    {

        Transacciones t = new Transacciones();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable tabla_Intervalo = new DataTable();
        DataTable tabla_imagenIntervalo = new DataTable();
        ds = t.Mostrar_Intervalo(id_Intervalo, Sucursal, id_Rol);
        tabla_Intervalo = ds.Tables[0];            
        tabla_imagenIntervalo = ds.Tables[1];


        string datos = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tabla_Intervalo, Formatting.Indented);


        return datos;   

    }
```

```js
function obtener_intervalo() {


    var persona = 1;
    var Sucursal = "";
    var id_Rol = 1;
    
    if (persona != 0) {

    
    var valores;
    var datafields_bonos = new Array();
    var columns_bonos = new Array();
    var columnsArray = [];

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "frmPersona.aspx/Persona",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: '{id_Persona:"' + persona + '",Sucursal:"' + Sucursal + '",id_Rol:"' + id_Rol + '"}',
        async: false,

        success: function(data) {
            alert("Entro correcto");

            if (data != '') {
                valores = jQuery.parseJSON(data); // Aqui cuando lo ejecuto me marca error en la consola.
                for (var i in valores[0]) {
                    datafields_bonos.push({ name: i });//No me regresa ningun valor
                    columns_bonos.push({ text: i, datafield: i, width: 200 });//No me regresa ningun valor
                }

                for (var j = 1; j < columns_bonos.length; j++) {
                    columnsArray.push(columns_bonos[j]);
                    console.log(columnsArray);//No me retorna el resultado
                }

            }

            var gridSource =
                {
                    localdata: valores,
                    datatype: 'json'
                   
                };
```

Comment: ¿Qué error muestra? ¿Verificaste que todo está OK del lado del servidor? Puede que esto: `valores = jQuery.parseJSON(data); ` no sea necesario, ya está indicado que se espera un JSON, aunque a veces depende del manejo que haces en el servidor y cómo emites la respuesta, con un header adecuado... Haz un `console.log(data);`  sin más a ver qué muestra.

Comment: Otra cosa, `data` se puede crear así: `data: {id_Persona: persona, Sucursal: Sucursal, id_Rol: id_Rol }`  no sé por qué te complicas la vida usando comillas, no es necesario.

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano coloque un punto de interrupción y los datos me los regresa correctamente en forma de cadena. Es por ello que lo quiero parsear y convertirlo en un array de objetos json. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Function.jQuery.parseJSON (jquery-1.11.1.js:8482)
    at Object.success (Prueba.js:91).

Estos son los errores que me muestra.

Comment: *`Unexpected token o in JSON `*  hace pensar que no estás devolviendo un JSON válido desde el servidor. Como te dije, imprime el valor de `data` del success en la consola, cópialo y valídalo en [`jsonlint.com`](https://jsonlint.com) si no pasa la validación no podrás hacer nada, debes devolver un JSON válido sí o sí. En el servidor debes vigilar que por pantalla no salga nada, pero nada de nada más que el JSON. Con que salga un simple espacio en blanco por pantalla invalidará el JSON.

Comment: podrias colocar un ejemplo minimo de la respuesta recibida, el json ya que todos los que intentan ayudarte solo pueden especular. pero no sabemos en realidad que estas recibiendo y si es en json u otro formato!

Comment: agregala a tu pregunta!

Comment: Hola @Bryro ya la agregue la cadena a la publicación.

Comment: eso es todo el texto???

Comment: @Bryro el texto es larguísimo solo coloco una parte, todo el texto contiene lo mismo.

Comment: El resultado que muestras `"[\r\n  {\r\n    \"id_Persona\": 1,\r\n    \"Sucursal\":  ...` no puede ser un JSON válido. Debes revisar lo que ocurre en el servidor, ocupándote de que el mismo devuelva un JSON válido. Esto debe ser observado estrictamente en las peticiones Ajax que esperan por respuesta un JSON. Por ejemplo, ¿por qué el servidor te devuelve esos saltos de linea una y otra vez `\r\n`?

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano he colocado todo el código en la nueva actualización de mi publicación.